# Why am I getting a login prompt after installation of ubuntu 12.04.1?

Tags: 12.04, login, lts

I just installed Ubuntu lts 12.04.1 on my computer from CD using option 2 to wipe Windows from it. The first time I received an error when the computer tried to restart so I reinstalled, but now, when it boots, all I get is some text and a login prompt (a terminal). Can anyone help?

Screenshot of what I'm seeing:
[image]

Comment: Do you have some graphic card installed in your computer? this may be due to absence of desired drivers, usually happens with ATI Cards

Comment: @DaimyoKirby that is not what I am seeing. I am trying to get image posted now.

Comment: Because I am a new user I cannot post images. But I will try all suggestions.

Comment: Ah, ok. If you get a screenshot, upload it to imgur and link to it, we'll edit it into the post.

Answer (score 0):

A login prompt is normal, just login to your user like you would on any computer.

Comment: I'm sorry...I should have clarified, it's a terminal login prompt and when I put my username and password in it tells me info on how many packages that are and how many updates then gives me $ prompt.

Comment: I only know enough to get me in trouble in a terminal...sorry. lol

Comment: Are you by any chance using the server edition instead of the desktop one?

Comment: No, I even double checked, it is the desktop image.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the login manager from the terminal?

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

Comment: What happens if/when you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu might be automatically opening one of the terminals instead of the normal screen - try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>; this should open the first xscreen, if Ubuntu is loading correctly.